# Image map change image on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, imagemap

I have a problem and would love some help!
For my website I would like to have an interactive header.
I made an image map for a character on the header which when clicked redirects to the about page.

I would like to switch the image when it hovers over the image map.
From reading I discovered I could change class b when hovering class a with
Sibling markers ~ or + I tried these respectively but they didn't work.

Here is the html concerning the header image and image map.

```
    <div class="td-main-content-wrap td-main-page-wrap">
            <div class="td-container">
                <div class="vc_row wpb_row td-pb-row"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span12"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <a href="http://breakline.nl/about/meet-giovanni-boerstra/" class="giomap" title="Meet Gio!" style="position: absolute; left: 70.63%; top: 20.32%; width: 13.85%; height: 39.57%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="http://breakline.nl/about/meet-stef-verkooijen/" class="stefmap" title="Meet Stef!" style="position: absolute; left: 17.6%; top: 44.28%; width: 14.38%; height: 50.74%; z-index: 2;"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center   superheroheader">

    <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="1920" height="743" src="http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="Testheadersuperhero2" srcset="http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2.jpg 1920w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-300x116.jpg 300w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-768x297.jpg 768w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-1024x396.jpg 1024w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-696x269.jpg 696w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-1068x413.jpg 1068w, http://breakline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Testheadersuperhero2-1085x420.jpg 1085w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px"></div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

And the CSS I tried for the imageswap with + as I thought that would do it.

```
    .stefmap:hover + .superheroheader img{
visibility:hidden;}
    .stefmap:hover + .superheroheader {
background-image:url(wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Testheadersuperhero2hover.jpg);
background-size:cover;}
```

You might wanna have a look at the [Website](http://breakline.nl) if anything is unclear.
And Check out the superman character in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The reason your sibling selector "+" isn't working is because you're targeting a div that is not a sibling.

So you're doing this:

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <a class="giomap""></a>
        <!-- target hover-->
        <a class="stefmap""></a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- target image change-->
<div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center   superheroheader">
</div>
```

In order for your CSS to work, you need to change your HTML so that your target hover is on the same line as your target image change (therefore making them siblings). I've tested moving the below using the browser inspector and it doesn't seem to mess up your layout, but its possible you may need to rejig the rest of the header css to accommodate for the change.

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <a class="giomap""></a>
    </div>
 </div>

 <!-- target hover-->
 <a class="stefmap""></a>

 <!-- target image change-->
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center   superheroheader">
 </div>
```

Comment: Aah amazing this has helped me understand the sibling connector way better, and I was able to recreate it in the browser. One problem though, how do I change this in the wordpress html genererated code?

Comment: Fixed it! Instead of putting out a seperate raw code and seperate image. I combined the 2 codes as you described as one raw code block and it works! Thanks alot :D